# combining two jquery functions

Tags: jquery

```
function altcat(id) {
        $ogzu = id;
    }       
    function okaycity(id) {
        jQuery("#okay").load("ajax_post_category.php?okay="+id+"");
        $ugur = id;
    }
```

how can i combine these two functions? i want them to work like as one function. i tried so many ways, however couldnt done it.i googled, couldnt find a way. can anyone save me?
regards

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you have some HTML to show?

Answer (score 2):

```
function altcat(id) {
    $ogzu = id;
}       
function okaycity(id) {
    jQuery("#okay").load("ajax_post_category.php?okay="+id+"");
    $ugur = id;
}

function combined(id) {
    altcat(id);
    okaycity(id);
}
```

I'm confused :-S

Comment: captain obvious to the rescue :D j/k +1 ... from what I can tell thats really all he want to do...

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the question:

```
function combinedVersion(id) {
    $ogzu = id;
    jQuery("#okay").load("ajax_post_category.php?okay="+id+"");
    $ugur = id;
}
```

If you want to preserve their earlier names (because something is calling them by that name, and you can't update it to use a new name), you can add this to the above:

```
var altcat = combinedVersion;
var okaycity = combinedVersion;
```

Then, calling `altcat()`, `okaycity()`, or `combinedVersion()` will all call the same function. You will want to make sure that the two `var` statements there are above things that may use them. At the top of the function (if this is within a function) or page (if it's at global scope) would be best.

So if this is at global scope:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var altcat = combinedVersion;
var okaycity = combinedVersion;
function combinedVersion(id) {
    $ogzu = id;
    jQuery("#okay").load("ajax_post_category.php?okay="+id+"");
    $ugur = id;
}
</script>
```

...or if it's inside a function:

```
function foo() {
    var altcat = combinedVersion;
    var okaycity = combinedVersion;
    function combinedVersion(id) {
        $ogzu = id;
        jQuery("#okay").load("ajax_post_category.php?okay="+id+"");
        $ugur = id;
    }
}
```